# Magento 1.9 How to send a pdf invoice download link to order delivered email?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, pdf, download-link

I'd like to know `how I can send an email with a link to direct download the PDF invoice`.

I'm using magento 1.9.2.4.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You want to send pdf download link or in attachment

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies I need to send a pdf download link.